# How do I correctly reference a private Windows assembly in the Application Manifest?

Tags: c++, winapi, cmake, dll, mt

## My setup and what I try to achieve

My project is set up to use **CMake**, **Ninja** as my generator and **MSVC** as my compiler. I have an executable target `A.exe` and 2 shared library targets (`B.dll` and `C.dll`). I'm on Windows and use load-time linking by linking to their static counterparts `B.lib` and `C.lib`. The dependency of this targets goes as follows: `A.exe` -> `B.dll` -> `C.dll` (read "->" as "depends on").

Everything compiles and builds successfully, but when I try run the program I get this error:

`The Application has failed to start because its side to side configuration is incorrect`

The basic folder structure of my project:

```
\
 | - A.cpp
 | - B.cpp
 | - C.cpp
 | - A.manifest
 | - B.manifest
 | - C.manifest
 | - CMakeListst.txt
```

### Code

#### CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22.0)
project(test VERSION 0.1.0)

add_executable(
    A
    "A.cpp"
    "A.manifest"
)


add_library(
    B
    SHARED
    "B.cpp"
    "B.manifest"
)

add_library(
    C
    SHARED
    "C.cpp"
    "C.manifest"
)

target_link_libraries(B C) # B -> C
target_link_libraries(A B) # A -> B
```

#### CPP files

A.cpp:

```
__declspec(dllimport) void B_test();

int main()
{
    B_test();
    return 0;
}
```

B.cpp:

```
__declspec(dllimport) void C_test();

__declspec(dllexport) void B_test()
{
    C_test();
}
```

C.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

__declspec(dllexport) void C_test()
{
    std::cout << "Success" << std::endl;
}
```

#### Manifests

A.manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<assembly
        xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"
        manifestVersion="1.0"
        >

    <assemblyIdentity
            type="win32"
            name="A"
            language="*"
            processorArchitecture="amd64"
            version="1.0.0.0"
            />
            
    <dependency>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity
                    type="win32"
                    name="B"
                    language="*"
                    processorArchitecture="amd64"
                    version="1.0.0.0"
                    />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </dependency>

</assembly>
```

B.manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<assembly
        xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"
        manifestVersion="1.0"
        >

    <assemblyIdentity
            type="win32"
            name="B"
            language="*"
            processorArchitecture="amd64"
            version="1.0.0.0"
            />

    <dependency>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity
                    type="win32"
                    name="C"
                    language="*"
                    processorArchitecture="amd64"
                    version="1.0.0.0"
                    />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </dependency>

    <file name="B.dll" />

</assembly>
```

C.manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<assembly
        xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"
        manifestVersion="1.0"
        >
    <!-- details about our side-by-side assembly-->
    <assemblyIdentity
            type="win32"
            name="C"
            language="*"
            processorArchitecture="amd64"
            version="1.0.0.0"
            />

    <file name="C.dll" />
</assembly>
```

### What I tried

- As I read from the Microsoft Documentation, the `C.manifest` isn't actually necessary and all `.dll` files should be referenced in `B.manifest`, but that doesn't work either.
- I tried to avoid using manifests, but if I do so, I get the same exact error.

What I wanted is to make my `A.exe` depend on `B.dll` which also depends on `C.dll`. I would like to know where I'm wrong and what can I do to achieve my goal.

Comment: Usually I see stuff like this when the installed Visual Studio runtime libraries aren't quite right.

Comment: Can you please read about [the problems with images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to **add a transcription** of your images of the error message as actual text? Perhaps useful: [/help/formatting](/help/formatting).

Comment: Related: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/the-application-has-failed-to-start-because-its/634458e4-e02f-4bdc-aab8-c148a9a3f61a

Comment: You can look at the Windows Event Viewer, it usually adds information to SxS errors. Also I kinda remember (not 100% sure) that you only need to declare dependencies in .exe manifest, not in each dll. So you should put B and C deps in A and remove deps from B.

Comment: Here's a tip: You can press [CTRL]+C for any standard message box (like the error dialog) and have it copy a textual representation of the dialog into the clipboard. As for diagnosing the issue, you can enable [loader snaps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/show-loader-snaps) and run the application with a debugger attached. The [fuslogvw.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/fuslogvw-exe-assembly-binding-log-viewer) might be useful, too.

Comment: @IInspectable, Thanks for the useful tip I'll checkout your advice i bit later and try to debug it.

Comment: @SimonMourier, I'll check the Event Viewer for any hints to resolving the error. I'll try to reference the .dll's in the application file as well and see if that works.

Comment: @SimonMourier, the Event Viewer tells me that Windows can't find the `B.dll` assembly, though the `<assemblyIdentity>` tags are equal. Removing the "`B.dll` -> `C.dll`" dependency didn't help as the problem is with the `A.exe`'s manifest as far as I can understand.

Comment: A should declare B and C dlls

Comment: @IInspectable, I enabled the loader snaps through `gflags.exe` and fired up the WinDbg. There I clicked `File`->`Open Executable...` and chose my debug build of `A.exe`. When I clicked `OK` I was presented with basically the same exact error, but just in a different dialog. For now I can't paste the error message here, because the machine I'm working on right now isn't using English and I can't change it, but I will add this to the question body in a couple of hours' time. What other steps can I do to solve the issue?

Comment: @SimonMourier, in the `<dependentAssembly>` section of Applicaiton Manifest?

Comment: @SimonMourier, I did in fact added the `<file>` tags with the `B.dll` and `C.dll`. I also tried to add them to the Application manifest but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Loader snaps print information to the attached debugger's output log. As an aside, this doesn't require debug symbols. You can attach to a release configuration just as well.

Comment: @IInspectable, could you please explain how can I save or view this log, or give the link explaining it? I couldn't find it in the web.

Comment: I think I've managed to make it work! I'll post the solution! Thanks IInspectable and SimonMourier for your help a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of fellow programmers in the comments and a bit of adding and removing lines from `.manifest` files I finally made it work. Thanks to Simon Mourier

> A should declare B and C dlls –
> Simon Mourier

What I was wrong about is declaring my `B.dll` and `C.dll` as separate private assemblies. What I had to do, in fact, is add the `<file>` tags to `A.manifest` as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<assembly
        xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1"
        manifestVersion="1.0"
        >

    <assemblyIdentity
            type="win32"
            name="A"
            language="cpp"
            processorArchitecture="amd64"
            version="1.0.0.0"
            />
    <!-- Added the .dll's to application manifest -->
    <file name="B.dll" />
    <file name="C.dll" />

</assembly>
```

Also, the `B.manifest` and `C.manifest` were no longer needed, and I excluded them from the build:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22.0)
project(test VERSION 0.1.0)

add_executable(
    A
    "A.cpp"
    "A.manifest"
)

# removed "B.manifest"
add_library(
    B
    SHARED
    "B.cpp"
)

# removed "C.manifest"
add_library(
    C
    SHARED
    "C.cpp"
)

target_link_libraries(B C) # B -> C
target_link_libraries(A B) # A -> B
```

With that, everything works just fine and outputs correct